# libusb_interrupt_transfer LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT

Tags: c++

I have a general design question, the final software will eventually run on Linux and Windows...

I am trying to read 8 bytes on an endpoint with libusb_interrupt_transfer and LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT occurs in the middle of data being received...  Will the be data be broken up? The docs warn about specifying anything other than the actual endpoint data size for the 'length' variable of the data to be received; that it can lead to buffer overrun. Also the docs say that if a timeout occurs to check the 'transferred' variable and that not all the data may have been received. Those two things being true, How am I supposed to deal with partially received data? If LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT occurs and my packet is only 8 bytes, will all 8 bytes always be received? And I supposed to always supply an 8 byte buffer, even if I am only requesting to receive the next 2 bytes to complete a previously timed out read request? And if I do supply that 8 byte buffer, and only request 2 bytes, it is possible that I may end up with 6 bytes of the next data packet that is incoming? Even though I only requested 2 bytes? Any info is greatly appreciated.

http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__syncio.html#gac412bda21b7ecf57e4c76877d78e6486
libusb docs states "Also check transferred when dealing with a timeout error code. libusb may have to split your transfer into a number of chunks to satisfy underlying O/S requirements"

http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/packetoverflow.html
docs states: "When requesting data on a bulk endpoint, libusb requires you to supply a buffer and the maximum number of bytes of data that libusb can put in that buffer. However, the size of the buffer is not communicated to the device - the device is just asked to send any amount of data."

Then it also states: "Overflows can only happen if the final packet in an incoming data transfer is smaller than the actual packet that the device wants to transfer. Therefore, you will never see an overflow if your transfer buffer size is a multiple of the endpoint's packet size: the final packet will either fill up completely or will be only partially filled."

```
unsigned char data[8];
int timeout  = 250; //timeout in milliseconds
int xmtcnt = 0; 
int rcvcnt = 0;

//EP OUT (Send data to USB Device)
//0x02 = Endpoint Type 0x00 + Endpoint Number 2
r = libusb_interrupt_transfer(devh,0x02, data, sizeof(data), &xmtcnt, timeout);
if(r != 0 || xmtcnt != 8){printf("XMT libusb_interrupt_transfer error %d\n",r); goto out_release;}

//EP IN (Recv data from USB device)
//0x81 = Endpoint Type 0x80 + Endpoint Number 1     
//-----IS IT POSSIBLE TO RECEIVE LESS THAN 8 BYTES IF WE TIMEOUT?----   
r = libusb_interrupt_transfer(devh,0x81, data, sizeof(data), &rcvcnt, timeout);
if(r != 0 || rcvcnt != 8){printf("RCV libusb_interrupt_transfer error %d\n",r); goto out_release;}      

//show data received
CONSOLE("data: %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d xmt:%d rcv:%d\n",data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7],xmtcnt,rcvcnt);
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I added some example code, basically I am wondering if libusb_interrupt_transfer can receive less than 8 bytes if we timeout, I would expect not, but I am not 100% sure if that is a condition I need to handle. I believe that Windows and Linux will not break apart an interrupt transfer of 8 bytes. But not sure what is happening with libusb under the hood.

Comment: so far I have not been able to invoke a condition where a timeout will breakup the 8bytes of interrupt data. If that changes I will post an update. I am currently testing under Debian Linux.